# VB.net Find smallest number except 0

Tags: vb.net

I have five values where it is possble that one or multiple values are 0. There is a minimum of two values greater than 0.

What is, using VB.net, the easiest and cleanest way to find the smallest value of these values and ignore values that are 0?

EDIT:
I am this far:

```
'get smalles value that is not 0
Dim heights As List(Of Double) 
heights.Add(sectionHeight1)
heights.Add(sectionHeight2)
heights.Add(sectionHeight3)
heights.Add(sectionHeight4)
heights.Add(sectionHeight5)
        
For i = 0 To 4 Step 1
    If heights(i) = 0 Then
        heights.RemoveAt(i)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: have u a try to show? Why no put it in list and make a link query where xx>0 with order by and select first

Comment: I added to my post what I already have.

Comment: Side note.  In your original code above, when you want to remove items from a list while iterating over them, go BACKWARDS.

Comment: @Idle_Mind Can you tell me why backwards is better? I am still learning.

Comment: Because when moving forwards, as you delete an item, everything shifts down to fill the deleted slot.  This means you have to REPEAT that same index as it has something new in it.  This does not occur when you iterate BACKWARDS.  If you delete an item when moving backwards, everything before that spot has not moved so you can simply decrement your index like normal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's exactly the kind of problem that's best solved with LINQ:

```
Dim minValueIgnoring0 = heights.Where(Function(h) h <> 0).Min()
```

Alternative syntax:

```
Dim minValueIgnoring0 = (From h in heights Where h <> 0).Min()
```

(Note that you might need to add `Imports System.Linq` at the top of your source file.)

---

Note that LINQ can operate on arrays as well, so you don't even need the list:

```
Dim heights = {sectionHeight1, sectionHeight2, sectionHeight3, sectionHeight4, sectionHeight5}
Dim minValueIgnoring0 = heights.Where(Function(h) h <> 0).Min()
```

---

Learn more:

- [.NET Docs: Introduction to LINQ in Visual Basic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/linq/introduction-to-linq)

Comment: That is what I was looking for. I will read on Linq more for the future. Thank you!