# how to get Min value from row exclude 0 (Ignore 0) in RDLC

Tags: vb.net, rdlc

i have an RCDL Report in the summation group row, need to get Min value from summation group row exclude 0

this Example for need
[image]

**i used this expression but it still return 0:**

```
=IIf ( 
ReportItems!x7s.Value <> 0
AND ReportItems!x7s.Value <= ReportItems!x8s.Value 
AND ReportItems!x7s.Value <= ReportItems!x9s.Value 
AND ReportItems!x7s.Value <= ReportItems!x10s.Value
AND ReportItems!x7s.Value <= ReportItems!x11s.Value 
AND ReportItems!x7s.Value <= ReportItems!x12s.Value , ReportItems!x7s.Value

, ( 
     iif (ReportItems!x8s.Value <> 0
AND ReportItems!x8s.Value <= ReportItems!x7s.Value 
AND ReportItems!x8s.Value <= ReportItems!x9s.Value 
AND ReportItems!x8s.Value <= ReportItems!x10s.Value
AND ReportItems!x8s.Value <= ReportItems!x11s.Value 
AND ReportItems!x8s.Value <= ReportItems!x12s.Value , ReportItems!x8s.Value

, ( 
     iif (ReportItems!x9s.Value <> 0
AND ReportItems!x9s.Value <= ReportItems!x7s.Value 
AND ReportItems!x9s.Value <= ReportItems!x8s.Value 
AND ReportItems!x9s.Value <= ReportItems!x10s.Value
AND ReportItems!x9s.Value <= ReportItems!x11s.Value 
AND ReportItems!x9s.Value <= ReportItems!x12s.Value , ReportItems!x9s.Value

, ( 
     iif (ReportItems!x9s.Value <> 0
AND ReportItems!x10s.Value <= ReportItems!x7s.Value 
AND ReportItems!x10s.Value <= ReportItems!x8s.Value 
AND ReportItems!x10s.Value <= ReportItems!x9s.Value
AND ReportItems!x10s.Value <= ReportItems!x11s.Value 
AND ReportItems!x10s.Value <= ReportItems!x12s.Value , ReportItems!x9s.Value , ReportItems!x11s.Value
)
)
)
)
)
)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

**thanks a lot I got the Solution**

```
=IIf ( 
ReportItems!x7s.Value <> 0
AND ReportItems!x7s.Value <= (iif(ReportItems!x8s.Value = 0 , ReportItems!x7s.Value , ReportItems!x8s.Value  ))
AND ReportItems!x7s.Value <= (iif(ReportItems!x9s.Value = 0 , ReportItems!x7s.Value , ReportItems!x9s.Value  ))
AND ReportItems!x7s.Value <= (iif(ReportItems!x10s.Value = 0 , ReportItems!x7s.Value ,ReportItems!x10s.Value ))
AND ReportItems!x7s.Value <= (iif(ReportItems!x11s.Value = 0 , ReportItems!x7s.Value ,ReportItems!x11s.Value )) 
, ReportItems!x7s.Value

, ( 
     iif (ReportItems!x8s.Value <> 0
AND ReportItems!x8s.Value <= (iif(ReportItems!x7s.Value = 0 , ReportItems!x8s.Value , ReportItems!x7s.Value  ))
AND ReportItems!x8s.Value <= (iif(ReportItems!x9s.Value = 0 , ReportItems!x8s.Value , ReportItems!x9s.Value  ))
AND ReportItems!x8s.Value <= (iif(ReportItems!x10s.Value = 0 , ReportItems!x8s.Value ,ReportItems!x10s.Value ))
AND ReportItems!x8s.Value <= (iif(ReportItems!x11s.Value = 0 , ReportItems!x8s.Value ,ReportItems!x11s.Value ))
 , ReportItems!x8s.Value

, ( 
     iif (ReportItems!x9s.Value <> 0
AND ReportItems!x9s.Value <= (iif(ReportItems!x7s.Value = 0 , ReportItems!x9s.Value , ReportItems!x7s.Value  ))
AND ReportItems!x9s.Value <= (iif(ReportItems!x8s.Value = 0 , ReportItems!x9s.Value , ReportItems!x8s.Value  ))
AND ReportItems!x9s.Value <= (iif(ReportItems!x10s.Value = 0 , ReportItems!x9s.Value ,ReportItems!x10s.Value ))
AND ReportItems!x9s.Value <= (iif(ReportItems!x11s.Value = 0 , ReportItems!x9s.Value ,ReportItems!x11s.Value )) 
, ReportItems!x9s.Value

, ( 
     iif (ReportItems!x10s.Value <> 0
AND ReportItems!x10s.Value <= (iif(ReportItems!x7s.Value = 0 , ReportItems!x10s.Value , ReportItems!x7s.Value  ))
AND ReportItems!x10s.Value <= (iif(ReportItems!x8s.Value = 0 , ReportItems!x10s.Value , ReportItems!x8s.Value  ))
AND ReportItems!x10s.Value <= (iif(ReportItems!x9s.Value = 0 , ReportItems!x10s.Value ,ReportItems!x9s.Value ))
AND ReportItems!x10s.Value <= (iif(ReportItems!x11s.Value = 0 , ReportItems!x10s.Value ,ReportItems!x11s.Value ))  
, ReportItems!x10s.Value , ReportItems!x11s.Value
)
)
)
)
)
)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

[VB.net Find smallest number except 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66599877/vb-net-find-smallest-number-except-0)

Check the answer on this question. I think this is what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your answer
but i need it in RDLC (Report Viewr)